# How to install plugin on github to Kibana running on Container

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, containers, kibana

I'd like to install the following plugin to Kibana running on container.
https://github.com/istresearch/kibana-object-format

However, as I am new to Kibana, I don't know how to install it. Its readme page says I should refer the official guide page below, but it doesn't help me at all. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/_installing_plugins.html.

The plugin is not listed in the known plugin list. So I guess it should be downloaded from github and install it. But I don't know how.

The images which I am testing now are below.

- docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:5.6.2
- kibana:5.5.2

Any suggestions or comments would be help. 
Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You can download plugins and install in your container if you create a Dockerfile for instance. This will allow you to have an image turning Kibana including the plugin.

Kibana has this command to install plugins: `kibana-plugin install`

For instance, adding the plugin KNQL could be done this way:

```
FROM kibana:5.6.6

ENV PATH /usr/share/kibana/bin:$PATH

# Documentation https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-docker-plugin-management
RUN kibana-plugin install \
"https://github.com/ppadovani/KibanaNestedSupportPlugin/releases/download/5.6.6-1.0.2/nested-fields-support-5.6.6-1.0.2.zip"

# curl and jq are used for the healthcheck
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl jq

HEALTHCHECK --interval=1s \
--retries=600 \
CMD curl -f http://localhost:5601/api/status | jq '. | .status.overall.state' | grep -q green
```

As you can see I've added a Healtcheck at the end, check the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck) to learn more about this.